# Undefined is not a function SwitchNavigator error

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React Native and create a navigation. But this module gives an "undefined is not a dunction SwitchNavigator" fault. How can i fix?

I know relased 2.0.x but i don't want use. Because that is gives;

> Cannot listen for a key that isn't associated with a Redux store. First call **createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware** so that we know when to trigger your listener

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZeeM.png)

**react-navigation**    1.0.0-beta.15 
**react-native**        expo

```js
const NonAuthNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Main: { screen: Main },
        Login: { screen: Login },
        Register: { screen: Register },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Main",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);
const AuthTabNavigator = TabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        Camera: { screen: Camera },
        Document: { screen: Document },
        Settings: { screen: Settings },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);
const LeftButtonNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Menu: { screen: Menu },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Main",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);
const AuthMainNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        AuthTabNav: { screen: AuthTabNavigator },
        LeftButtonNav: { screen: LeftButtonNavigator }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "AuthTabNav",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);
const AppNavigator = SwitchNavigator(
    {
        NonAuthNav: NonAuthNavigator,
        AuthMainNav: AuthMainNavigator,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'NonAuthNav',
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);
```